# Use set in a case statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to set a variable in SQL Server using a `CASE` statement. For  example:

```
DECLARE @UNITY VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @AUX VARCHAR(5)

CASE
    WHEN @UNITY = 'U1' THEN @AUX = 'M1'
    WHEN @UNITY = 'U2' THEN @AUX = 'M2'
    WHEN @UNITY = 'U3' THEN @AUX = 'M3'
END
```

Comment: Sql `CASE` is not a statement  like `if` or something. It's an expession which can be used on in a proper place of the statement: `set @AUX  = CASE    WHEN @UNITY = 'U1' THEN  'M1' ..`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as a flow control. An SQL `case` is an expression that return a scalar value based on condition(s).
It's well documented in the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) section:

> The CASE expression cannot be used to control the flow of execution of Transact-SQL statements, statement blocks, user-defined functions, and stored procedures. For a list of control-of-flow methods, see [Control-of-Flow Language (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/control-of-flow?view=sql-server-2017).

A working code would be written like this:

```
DECLARE @UNITY VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @AUX VARCHAR(5)

SET @AUX = 
CASE @UNITY
    WHEN 'U1' THEN 'M1'
    WHEN 'U2' THEN 'M2'
    WHEN 'U3' THEN 'M3'
END
```

Note I'm using the Simple CASE expression syntax for brevity.

Comment: I see it was that simple. I didn't think of this

Comment: Glad to help :-)